# Is there some advantage to filling a stack with nils and interpreting the "top" as the last non-nil value?

Tags: ruby

While working on a [rubymonk](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/33-advanced-arrays/lessons/86-stacks-and-queues#solution4117) exercise, I am asked to implement a stack with a hard size limit. It should return 'nil' if I try to push too many values, or if I try to pop an empty stack.

My solution is below, followed by their solution. Mine passes every test I can give it in my IDE, while it fails rubymonk's test. But that isn't my question.

Question is, why did they choose to fill the stack with nils instead of letting it shrink and grow like it does in my version?

It just makes their code more complex.

Here's my solution:

```
class Stack
  def initialize(size)
    @max = size
    @store = Array.new
  end

  def pop
    empty? ? nil : @store.pop
  end

  def push(element)
    return nil if full?
    @store.push(element)
  end

  def size
    @store.size
  end

  def look
    @store.last
  end

  private

  def full?
    @store.size == @max
  end

  def empty?
    @store.size == 0
  end
end
```

and here is the accepted answer

```
class Stack
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @store = Array.new(@size)
    @top = -1
  end

  def pop
    if empty?
      nil
    else
      popped = @store[@top]
      @store[@top] = nil
      @top = @top.pred
      popped
    end
  end

  def push(element)
    if full? or element.nil?
      nil
    else
      @top = @top.succ
      @store[@top] = element
      self
    end
  end

  def size
    @size
  end

  def look
    @store[@top]
  end

  private

  def full?
    @top == (@size - 1)
  end

  def empty?
    @top == -1
  end
end
```

Comment: They are just complicating things, and wasting memory.

Comment: I thought it might be for efficiency of pre-allocating space, but I benchmarked both versions, and yours is also faster for stack sizes 1000 to 100000.

Comment: @Linuxios i disagree with you, they are just trying to show how to implement a stack. they are trying to teach stack(and how it is implemented) , not `array.push` and `array.pop`. Its like saying that someone is trying to teach how to make a http call using curl and we say that is way too complicated we will use httparty gem. I guess we all are missing the point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess why they did it this way is because they did not want to  use `array.pop` and  `array.push` that you are using in your solution.
Thats a tutorial and you are learning to implement a STACK , so if you use inbuilt methods given by ruby array( `pop` and `push`) , then thats pretty useless :) .

So basically they are trying to make things less abstract for you, so you need to forget that ruby already contain `pop` and `push` and then write a solution and it will exactly look like their solution after that.

I do not mean to criticize you, just saying that whats the point of this exercise.

Remember in college we spend all our time implementing stacks and sockets and stuff and later we realized that for very stuff their is an extension defined. So i suggest unlearn all what you know once and then do these exercises :) .

Comment: OK I didn't even notice they were deliberately avoiding push and pop. So that's their point. Thx

Comment: Yes :) .With `pop` and `push` ruby array is already a stack. 
`irb(main):055:0> [].pop
=> nil` . So if you rely on ruby's `pop` and `push`, solution is already implemented , you just need to put a Max criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Their solution does not test for nil when it tries to find the top.

They use the @top value as the index of the topmost element and increment and decrement it whenever a new element gets added or removed. This is done through the `@top.succ` and `@top.pred` method calls.

<strike>There is no particular reason, why they fill their stack with nils, when something gets popped. In theory they could just decrease the @top counter and leave whatever was at that stack position stay there.</strike> As @Jan Dvorak pointed out the stack is filled with nils again to prevent memory leaking from the garbage collector.

Your version relies on the implementation of Array.pop and Array.push. Those may very well not actually shrink the allocated space, when popping a value, although I do not know the specific implementations of them.

Why constantly changing the size of an Array is a performance problem:

Lets say you want to create an Array of size 2. To do this ruby has to ask the operating system for a chunk of memory that is continuously unused and big enough to hold an Array of size 2. Lets say this requires 24 bytes.

So if you now want to push 3 values instead of only 2 you will have to request another chunk of memory from the operating system that now can hold the data for an Array of size 3. Lets say this requires 32 bytes. This new location might not be at the same place as your previous chunk of memory as it may be that after your previous 24 bytes another program has stored his own value. Now you have to copy your Array of size 2 to the new location and only then can you add your 3rd value to that array.

Now the point is that rubys Array class doesn't actually behave this way. It will very likely always request more memory than you initially tell it to from the operating system and will not decrease that memory after every pop. Furthermore it will probably not increase the requested memory by 1 Array element if it gets to big, but maybe just try to get twice as much memory at once when it runs out of memory.

Comment: I saw that and it just seemed a needless complication. On further thought, though, I  assume that static-sized stacks are somehow faster or more efficient than those that shrink and grow in size...

Comment: Ruby is probably not a very good language to demonstrate this, because it does all the acquiring of memory implicitly and you don't actually have to do it yourself. I will expand my answer a bit to show you the problem.

Comment: There is a reason to nil the positions you pop from: if you don't, your stack prevents garbage collection of the items that were recently popped or that were originally very deep. This could lead to substantial memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason why they implemented their solution that way. In my humble opinion, as someone who makes his living writing Ruby apps, your code is better.

(One difference is that they don't allow `nil`s to be pushed on the stack. That's probably why your code is failing their tests.)

Comment: woo hoo - now I can go on to the next exercise without (too much) shame! Thanks